# Button with background color and icon in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an icon and I want to make a button like the image, with a background color programmatically and the icon in the middle, but I don¡t know how to do it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: have you read this yet? `UIButton` Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image to UIButton using `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` method and color with `@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor` property

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)foo
{
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 30); // put here right numbers
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:84/255.0f green:114/255.0f blue:201/255.0f alpha:1];
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)myButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //do something...
}
```